# Android Build Variant Signing Config

Tags: android, gradle, signing, build-variant

I have the following in my android app module build.gradle file.

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }

    signingConfigs {
        if (System.getEnv()['CIRCLE-CI']) { /* CI System */
            localMachine { /* CI System KeyStore file and properties. */
                ...
                keyAlias = "ABC"
            }
            playStore { /* CI System KeyStore file and properties. */
                ...
                keyAlias = "ABC"
            }
        } else { /* Local machine, not CI System. */
            localMachine { /* debug.keystore local file and properties. */
                ...
                keyAlias = "androiddebugkey"
            }
            playStore { /* debug.keystore local file and properties. */
                ...
                keyAlias = "androiddebugkey"
            }
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        productOne {
            ...
        }
        productTwo {
            ...
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
        }
        release {
            ...
        }
    }
}

/** This is where the problem is **/
android.applicationVariants.all { variant -> 
        if (variant.mergedFlavor.name == "productOne") {
            if (variant.buildType.name == "debug") {
                variant.signingConfig android.signingConfigs.localMachine
            } else if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
                variant.signingConfig android.signingConfigs.playStore
            }
        } else if (variant.mergedFlavor.name == "productTwo") {
            if (variant.buildType.name == "debug") {
                variant.signingConfig android.signingConfigs.localMachine
            } else if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
                variant.signingConfig null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output is as follows.

```
productOneDebug -> Sign with signingConfigs.localMachine
productTwoDebug -> Sign with signingConfigs.localMachine
productOneRelease -> Sign with signingConfigs.playStore
productTwoRelease -> Unsigned.
```

Actual output is as follows.

```
productOneDebug -> Signed with signingConfigs.localMachine
productTwoDebug -> Signed with signingConfigs.localMachine
productOneRelease -> Unsigned.
productTwoRelease -> Unsigned.
```

Why are Release apks always unsigned?
The intention is to only have ProductTwo Release apk unsigned, but ProductOne Release apk should be signed based on the given configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is what happens during the Gradle Sync.

`Variant.signingConfig` is a Over-written mechanism from both Flavor and Build-type, in the same order, based on whether a value exists.

```
productOne.signingConfig = playStore
```

```
productTwo.signingConfig = null
```

```
debug.signingConfig = localMachine
```

```
release.signingConfig = null
```

And the resulting Variants will be -

```
productOneDebug.signingConfig = productOne.signingConfig
```

over-written by `debug.signingConfig`

```
productTwoDebug.signingConfig = productTwo.signingConfig
```

over-written by `debug.signingConfig`

```
productOneRelease.signingConfig = productOne.signingConfig
```

over-written by `release.signingConfig` if exists.

```
productTwoRelease.signingConfig = productTwo.signingConfig
```

over-written by `release.signingConfig` if exists.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, did you ever find a solution @AndroidRocks?

Answer (score 0):

I had a requirement like yours: I had two flavors (product-1 and product-2), and each one has different signing keystores.
So, this is what I did, and hope it helps you.

The signing configs were declared as:

```
...
signingConfigs {
    'prod-1-release' {
        storeFile file('product-1-release.keystore')
        storePassword '...'
        keyAlias '...'
        keyPassword '...'
    }
    'product-1-debug' {
        storeFile file('product-1-debug.keystore')
        storePassword '...'
        keyAlias '...'
        keyPassword '...'
    }
    'product-2-debug'{
        storeFile file('product-2-debug.keystore')
        storePassword '...'
        keyAlias '...'
        keyPassword '...'
    }
    'product-2-release'{
        storeFile file('product-2-release.keystore')
        storePassword '...'
        keyAlias '...'
        keyPassword '...'
    }

}
...
```

And then, I defined my flavors as this:

```
flavorDimensions=["the_flavor"]
productFlavors{
    product-1 {
        dimension "the_flavor"
        ...
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.'product-1-release'
            }
            debug {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.'product-1-debug
            }
    }
    product-2 {
        dimension "the_flavor"
        ...
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.'product-2-release'
            }
            debug {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.'product-2-debug'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All this is made in build.gradle file in :app level.

Hope this help you, and let the code be with you!